# Wordpress: Call a plugin function upon another functions ajax action?

Tags: php, ajax, wordpress, woocommerce

I am using a filter plugin for the shop page on Woocommerce with ajax activated.

In the filter plugin's constructor the call is as follows:

```
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_fltr_rspnd', __CLASS__ . '::fltr_rspnd' );
add_action( 'wp_ajax_fltr_rspnd', __CLASS__ . '::fltr_rspnd' );
```

Now a different plugin adds an overlay to my products that is called as follows:

```
add_action('plugins_loaded', 'run_mgs_over');
```

The function run_mgs_over is as follows:

```
function run_mgs_over(){
        Mgs_Over::loader();
  }
```

and the class for this call:

```
final class Mgs_Over{

  private static $instance = null;
  protected $textDomain='message-overlay';
        
  public static function loader(){
    self::$instance = new self();
    self::$instance->load_files();
    self::$instance->init_actions();
  }

  private function load_files(){
    require_once MSG_OVER_PLUGIN_PATH.'includes/class-msg-over-loader.php';
  }
  private function init_actions(){
    add_action('init', array($this, 'run'),0);
  }

  public function run(){
    $class='Msg_Over_front_end';
    new $class();
  }
   }
```

The add_action hook that actually does the overlay stems from the constructor in the class MGS_Front_End_Controller:

```
class MGS_Manager_Front_End_Controller{
  public function __construct(){
    add_action ('woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item',array($this,'custom_mgs'), 9);
  }
}
```

custom_mgs returns the message overlay in a span.

With this setup, the overlay shows on initial load but not any more after filter actions took place. Is it possible to call this woocommerce_before_shop_loop_item action within the functions.php and if so, what risks (despite plugin changes) can occur?

Comment: It would be more helpful, and you'd have more of a chance getting an answer if you include the relevant jQuery / Ajax functions. `run_mgs_over` triggers some other functions, and I would doubt this is the one that's relevant to your question.  See if you can find something more specific there.

Comment: I added calls from run_mgs_over that might help to grasp the issue.

Comment: What's in this file? `MSG_OVER_PLUGIN_PATH.'includes/class-msg-over-loader.php`

Comment: Thank you for leading me to the right path to figure this out. So I did some more digging and found the hook to display the message overlay and I suppose this is the one I need to add to functions.php the right way.